# Segregate unread from read rows in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have a large database to which data is added continuously and there are many users who consume the data. Based on some logic I select some rows from the database, send it to the users and mark it as read. But I feel this method is inefficient in that it reads very huge numbers of rows in which only 10s are unread and each time it takes long time to read entire database.

These are my questions

> 1, is there way to segregate unread rows from read ones so that I
>   easily select only unread rows from the database. And also there many users, finding unread rows for a particular user makes this still difficult.
>
> 2, What is the most efficient way to store which rows are read by
>   different users. For now, for each row I store all users who had read
>   that row. This method is also very inefficient in that there are large
>   number of users and data are consumed randomly by the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a separate table of `ReadRows` with two important columns `UserId` and `RowId`.  The `RowId` would be the id of a row read by a user.  Each user would have multiple rows in the table.  The process of marking a row as "read" is the process of inserting a row into this table.

You can keep this efficient by creating an index `ReadRows(UserId, RowId)`.  This will make it fast to access any given user's rows.

Comment: question states "For now, for each row I store all users who had read that row. " - so it appears poster is already doing what you suggest.

Comment: @MitchWheat . . . Maybe, maybe not.  The user could be storing the values in a comma-delimited list or in a table without the appropriate indexes.

Comment: Give the poster some credit -> "The user could be storing the values in a comma-delimited list"

Comment: Thanks :) In my scenario I'm more focused on getting the unread rows than read ones. Your solution gives if the row had been read by the user which involves checking if the row is present in ReadRows table for each row. Sometimes I need rows which are not read by anyone. Im curious, Is there way of doing is better?

Comment: @cyn0 . . . For rows that are not read by *anyone*, I would suggest having a flag in the original table.  You can also incorporate this flag into indexes, that can make it fast to lookup (assuming that there are a small number of unread rows in the table).